# @tensorflow/tfjs-node: tensorflow.dll version for no-AVX CPUs

Tags: node.js, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

TensorFlow doesn't provide binaries with **no-AVX CPUs** support [since version 1.6](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip). After a long time looking for a solution for this, I found a [GitHub repository](https://github.com/fo40225/tensorflow-windows-wheel) (thanks to the author) that put to the disposition of the community some wheels for no-AVX CPUs. I installed a `.whl` in my computer and it works like a charm.

I'm looking for something similar for Node JS. I have a project developed with `@tensorflow/tfjs-node` that works in a CPU with AVX support but it doesn't work in a CPU without AVX. If I try to execute it, I got an error realted with the DLL library:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1188
  return process.dlopen(module, path.toNamespacedPath(filename));
                 ^

Error: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
\\?\C:\tensorflow-node-2.0.1\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node\lib\napi-v6\tfjs_binding.node
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1188:18)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1026:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\tensorflow-node-2.0.1\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node\dist\index.js:58:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)
```

The DLL that triggers the error is:`node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node\lib\napi-v6\tensorflow.dll`.

I tried to install a previous version of `@tensorflow\tfjs-node` like this [GitHub issue says](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/2599) without success. I got the same error.

Is there any **`tensorflow.dll`** for no-AVX CPUs available?

Comment: The error has nothing to do with AVX instructions, it would not prevent you from loading a DLL.

Comment: If the error is not related with AVX instructions, what could be related to? Some GitHub issues like [this one](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/2619) refer to CPU instructions.

Comment: Please submit bugs to Github not here.